# Learning Theory in FOCS

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, advice-request, conferences

I work in learning theory and am looking for good venues to submit my paper.  Does one usually send learning theory papers to FOCS or is it more reasonable to send it to something like NeurIPS.  I just worry that its too technical for the NeurIPS audience...

Comment: there's also colt, alt, soda

Comment: How are these ranked wrt FOCS and, also, is FOCS (or any of these) particularly receptive to learning theory?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152253/discussion-on-question-by-abim-learning-theory-in-focs); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.